# Is there a way to override Jekyll's link validation when using the link tag?

Tags: tags, jekyll, liquid

Is there a way to override Jekyll's link validation when using the `{% link %}` tag?

Per the [Jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#linking-to-posts):

> One major benefit of using the `link` or `post_url` tag is link
> validation. If the link doesn’t exist, Jekyll won’t build your site.
> This is a good thing, as it will alert you to a broken link so you can
> fix it (rather than allowing you to build and deploy a site with
> broken links).

But I *want* to allow broken links in some of my documents - or at the very least, I want Jekyll to build the rest of my site.  Can I override this on a case-by-case basis (i.e. wrap the `link` tag with some other tag)?  Is there a `_config.yml` setting I can use?  A plugin?

And while I appreciate good-natured questions/suggestions such as "you shouldn't build a site with broken links!" please know this site is just for me, not the world at large.  I'll know what to do with my own 404, I promise :)

Comment: Try `ignore_missing_links: true` in `_config.yml` :)

Comment: No dice - and no information in the Jekyll docs that this is supported.

Comment: I also love 404's :) You could try to convert (broken) links to standard markdown links.